# while loop with break after first iteration is faster than if statement

Tags: c++, performance, time

I am solving a problem in Codeforce.com, and I was trying different approaches to find out which is the fastest.

I tried changing an if statement to a while loop which breaks from the first iteration (always).

To my surprise, it was faster by 16ms.

I know it is insignificant but than is interesting + important in Competitive Programming.

The time speed was like this:

1 iteration while loop: **15ms** -
if statement is **31ms**

Notes:

1. The rest of the code is exactly the same.
2. I used Codeforces's timing (tried it different times, still while loop is faster).

Here is the if statement full code:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std; 
 
int main ()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        int l, r, x, a, b, counter = 0;
        cin >> l >> r >> x;
        cin >> a >> b;
        if (a == b)
        {
            cout << 0 << "\n";
        }
        else if (b > r || b < l || x > abs(r - l) || (abs(r - a) < x && abs(l - a) < x) || abs (l - r) < x || (abs(r - b) < x && abs(l - b) < x))
        {
            cout << -1 << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            if (a != b)
            {
                if (abs(a - b) >= x)
                {
                    cout << 1 << "\n";
                }
                else if (abs(a - l) >= x && abs(b - l) >= x)
                {
                    cout << 2 << "\n";
                }
                else if (abs(a - r) >= x && abs(b - r) >= x)
                {
                    cout << 2 << "\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << 3 << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is while loop full code:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
  
int main ()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        int l, r, x, a, b, counter = 0;
        cin >> l >> r >> x;
        cin >> a >> b;
        if (a == b)
        {
            cout << 0 << "\n";
        }
        else if (b > r || b < l || x > abs(r - l) || (abs(r - a) < x && abs(l - a) < x) || abs(l - r) < x || (abs(r - b) < x && abs(l - b) < x))
        {
            cout << -1 << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            while (a != b)
            {
                if (abs(a - b) >= x)
                {
                    cout << 1 << "\n";
                    break;
                }
                else if (abs(a - l) >= x && abs(b - l) >= x)
                {
                    cout << 2 << "\n";
                    break;
                }
                else if (abs(a - r) >= x && abs(b - r) >= x)
                {
                    cout << 2 << "\n";
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << 3 << "\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure asm is identical and timing difference is unrelated.

Comment: i tried running the same 2 code multiple times and still the time difference stands @Jarod42

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: Timing from [quickbench](https://quick-bench.com/q/3d5_zfzNBA_VzesS9qROCx7oQi4).

Comment: Compiler optimizations enabled?

Comment: @JesperJuhl the code was run in codeforces judging system, so i can't know.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` `using namespace std;` - Don't. Do. That.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> iteration while loop: 15ms - if statement is 31ms

A comparison of two similar program with runtimes that only differ by 16ms is just a rounding error. It's unclear what optimization flags were used in compiling the program. On those coding competition sites, there's no guarantee that your programs run on the same computer, same VM, same container, or same load while it's evaluating other coding submissions for other users.

Also, programs not compiled with optimization flags can't really be compared fairly compared with each other in terms of performance. It's uncertain how the program was compiled.

A more appropriate benchmark would be to compile both programs locally with full optimizations and use an input size that would enable the program to run a full minute or longer.

Example:

Compile your first implementation as:

```
g++ prog1.cpp -o prog1 -O3
```

Then your second implementation as:

```
g++ prog2.cpp -o prog2 -O3
```

Then benchmark both together using multiple iterations each

```
time ./prog1 < input.txt > /dev/null   
time ./prog2 < input.txt > /dev/null
```

Where `input.txt` is a LARGE file with a million or so test cases generated with random numbers:

```
1000000
10 20 30 40 50 60
60 11 22 44 33 22
44 3 2 11 330 4 1
...
```

The `time` command measures "how long". The redirect to /dev/null eliminates the randomness of disk writes from the benchmark.

Try running the `prog1` statement 20+ times first followed by `prog2` the same number of times. That way, you get a high degree of caching and repeatability.

Using Godbolt, when you compare the compiles of both your programs on g++ with full optimizations, you can see the generated assembly of the [first version](https://www.godbolt.org/z/Ycs9zeM8b) is **identical** to the [second version](https://www.godbolt.org/z/MGPbWKqc1). So this entire discussion is more academic that helpful to the problem at hand. :)